# How a read a txt file in a array and then print in console some value in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem. I have a txt file with some value, and I try to use eclipse to read and parse that txt file in a array and then put some condition to write that array in console. The text that I use to read txt file and parse in array is this:

```
public void Transaction(String filepath, String user)
{
    String [] [] myArray = new String[100][3];

    Scanner scanIn = null;
    int Rowc = 0, Colc = 0;
    String InputLine = "";
    double xnum = 0;
    String username, tranzactie, info;
    try
    {
        scanIn = new Scanner ( new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)));           
        while(scanIn.hasNextLine())
        {


            InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
            String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");
            for(int x = 0; x<InArray.length; x++)
            {
                myArray[Rowc][x] = InArray[x];
            }
            Rowc++;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i<Rowc; i++)
        {
            for (Colc = 0; Colc < 3; Colc ++)
            {   

                System.out.print(myArray[i][Colc]+ ",");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

The txt file is this:

```
John,SoldInterogation
John,PayInvoice,He pay 30 EUR
Alex,PayInvoice,He pay 15 EUR
Alex,BankTransfer,He transfered 50 EUR
John,SoldInterogation
```

How can I write in the console just the transaction for john or Alex, or ... . What I must adding in my java code for do this? I must write only the transaction, this mean only the 2 column of the txt file, the user ( John, Alex) this musn't write in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test if InArray is length 3, and if it is : add its two last strings to a String variable.
Then just println this String variable after your reading loops.

```
try
{
    // A String variable to println after the reading.
    String consoleResume = "";
    scanIn = new Scanner ( new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)));           
    while(scanIn.hasNextLine())
    {


        InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
        String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");
        for(int x = 0; x<InArray.length; x++)
        {
            myArray[Rowc][x] = InArray[x];
        }
        // There is a transaction when you have 3 strings in InArray
        if (InArray.length()==3)
            consoleResume+=InArray[1]+":"+InArray[2]+"\n"; 
        Rowc++;

    }
    System.out.println(consoleResume);

}catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

You can also println the transactions inside your loop :

```
    try
{
    scanIn = new Scanner ( new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)));           
    while(scanIn.hasNextLine())
    {


        InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
        String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");
        for(int x = 0; x<InArray.length; x++)
        {
            myArray[Rowc][x] = InArray[x];
        }
        // There is a transaction when you have 3 strings in inArray
        if (InArray.length()==3)
            System.out.println(InArray[1]+":"+InArray[2]); 
        Rowc++;

    }


}catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```